# Lightning-input - Date/Time - Min and Max

Tags: lightninginput

In this: `<lightning-input type="datetime" name="EventStartDateTime">`

How do I set the min and max values for time ( 06:00 to 11 pm ) and Date (Min: Today and Max: Today +10 years) ?

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** do like the way you want. But you can set between two datetime as below:-

```
<lightning:input type="datetime" name="input5" label="Date Time field with min and max values" value="2017-09-12T18:13:41Z" min="2017-08-03T08:20:44Z" max="2017-09-25T22:33:44Z" />
```

As a workaround, You can write validation on the selected value of the input field.